# The pane on the left of the screen (2.83.18) shrunk while I was concentrating on my model

Tags: interface, panel

WHile I was building my model, I hit some hotkey or other, and the pane on the left of the screen shrunk (it shows the icons in Object mode, Edit mode, etc.)
I can now barely read it. The panel was far bigger before.
I can't find a way to make it readable again, despite spending some time in the preferences section.
Can any of you guys come up with a fix, please?
Even better, can you take a guess at how I messed it up in the first place?
Many thanks
P
[image]

Comment: move your cursor over it and use scrollwheel.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase/decrease the size of most areas using <kbd>Numpad +</kbd>/<kbd>Numpad -</kbd> keys
Just hover your cursor over the area.

[image]